# Cannot create polkadot keyring with react native

Tags: react-native, polkadot-js

I created a new react native project with this command:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

installed package @polkadot/keyring, and created a default keyring:

```
const keyring = new Keyring();
```

After launching the project I get an error:

```
TypeError: Conversion from 'BigInt' to 'number' is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libraries are just not ment to work with react native, only with node js or web client. This is one of those cases